# The current path, account/ active/muSxcXQedffNqDxt/, didn't match any of these

Tags: django

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEpKZ.png)

Why it didn't match the url 7?

urls.py:

```
path('active/(?P<active_code>.*)/$', ActiveUserView.as_view(), name='active_user'),
```

views.py:

```
class ActiveUserView(View):
    def get(self,request,active_code):
        users = UserProfile.objects.filter(code=active_code)
        if users:
            users.is_active = True
            users.save()
        else:
            users.delete()
            return HttpResponse('Fail！Register Again!')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("account:user_login"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
path('active/(?P<active_code>.*)/$', ActiveUserView.as_view(), name='active_user'),
```

this is the wrong for 2.0+ 
if you use this in django 2.0+ 
then first import re_path like this

```
from django.urls import re_path
re_path(r'active/(?P<active_code>.*)/$', ActiveUserView.as_view(), name='active_user')
```

after this working fine